# What is the purpose of generic socket structure?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

What is the purpose of generic socket structure?

```
struct sockaddr {
    unit8_t sa_len;
    sa_family_t sa_family;
    char sa_data[14];
}
```

Why can't we use `void *` instead?

Comment: Do you mean use `void *` instead of the `struct` or instead of an element of the `struct`?

Comment: This might have been invented before `void` was around.